# How to export functions from modules in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using **node.js (v4.2.2)** with **express (4.13.1)**. I am trying to import my custom module functions to another module. Application is created with express, and only thing added to app.js is require for my route `var tests = require('./routes/tests');` and app.use for that route `app.use('/tests', tests);`

My two custom files (modules) are (path is relative to project root):

- ./model/test.js
- ./routes/tests.js

Here is `./model/test.js`:

```
var id;
var testNumber1;
var testNumber2;

function Test(id, testNumber1, testNumber2) {
    this.id = id;
    this.testNumber1 = testNumber1;
    this.testNumber2 = testNumber2;
};

exports.reset = function() {
    this.testNumber1 = 0;
    this.testNumber2 = 0;
};

module.exports = Test;
```

And here is `./routes/tests.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var Red = require('../model/test.js');
var router = express.Router();

/*create new test :id*/
router.post('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var myNewTest = new Red(req.params.id, 0, 0)
  myNewTest.testNumber2 += 1;
  myNewTest.reset();
  res.send('id: ' + myNewTest.id + 
    ' testNumber2: ' + myNewTest.testNumber2);
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I try to execute `curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/tests/1` i get error `TypeError: myNewTest.reset is not a function`. I am having trouble understanding how to export functions correctly. If I understand this [api reference](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) correctly, to expose constructor of module, i have to use `module.exports = Test;`, but that doesn't expose `reset` function. So, to expose it I have declared it like `exports.reset = function() {...}`, but obviously, that doesn't work, at least not in my case.

Through some other answers I have also seen function being declared normally `function reset() {...}`, and exposed like `exports.reset = reset;`, which gives me the same error.

How do I expose reset function properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add it to the prototype, at the moment it's just a static method in your module, not attached to the Test constructor.

```
function Test(id, testNumber1, testNumber2) {
    this.id = id;
    this.testNumber1 = testNumber1;
    this.testNumber2 = testNumber2;
};

Test.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.testNumber1 = 0;
    this.testNumber2 = 0;
};

module.exports = Test;
```